# iOS HTTPS request to Rails Heroku debugging 401 error

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am attempting to adapt [this wenderlich tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/85528/user-accounts-ios-ruby-rails-swift) to Swift 3 syntax to create an iOS frontned with rails backend hosted on Heroku.

Let me know if there is any other code that would be good to share, but it seems like an auth issue. Here's where the authorization header is set for the request:

```
let basicAuthString = "\(HTTPHelper.API_AUTH_NAME):\(HTTPHelper.API_AUTH_PASSWORD)"
let utf8str = basicAuthString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
let base64EncodedString = utf8str?.base64EncodedString(options: Data.Base64EncodingOptions())

request.addValue("Basic \(base64EncodedString)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
```

I am having trouble telling how to debug these requests to begin with. If I step through the code in the debugger, the request object seems pretty flat, and if I print the request I just see the URL.

The request to the heroku server (also built from that tutorial) returns a 401, and it doesn't seem to be entering any of the rails methods. It just returns a 401 unauthorized:

```
2017-03-24T20:13:47.022176+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/api/signin" host=young-retreat-61850.herokuapp.com request_id=9d58e8f4-ee9f-4c73-babd-2a2ee5c82a4f fwd="73.83.200.10" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=13ms status=401 bytes=499 protocol=https
2017-03-24T20:13:47.014605+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/api/signin" for 73.83.200.10 at 2017-03-24 20:13:47 +0000
2017-03-24T20:13:47.020239+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ApiController#signin as */*
2017-03-24T20:13:47.020279+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"email"=>"dsadsadsa", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "api"=>{"email"=>"dsadsadsa", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
2017-03-24T20:13:47.020671+00:00 app[web.1]: Filter chain halted as #<Proc:0x007f6ae4d6f140@/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.5/lib/action_controller/metal/http_authentication.rb:71> rendered or redirected
2017-03-24T20:13:47.020791+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 401 Unauthorized in 0ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2017-03-24T20:13:47.142925+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/api/signin" for 73.83.200.10 at 2017-03-24 20:13:47 +0000
2017-03-24T20:13:47.148098+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ApiController#signin as */*
2017-03-24T20:13:47.148134+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"email"=>"dsadsadsa", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "api"=>{"email"=>"dsadsadsa", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
2017-03-24T20:13:47.156450+00:00 app[web.1]: Filter chain halted as #<Proc:0x007f6ae4d6f140@/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.5/lib/action_controller/metal/http_authentication.rb:71> rendered or redirected
2017-03-24T20:13:47.156647+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 401 Unauthorized in 8ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2017-03-24T20:13:47.157852+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/api/signin" host=young-retreat-61850.herokuapp.com request_id=bc270aa1-aeed-40b8-b9a0-3c09a68dec8d fwd="73.83.200.10" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=24ms status=401 bytes=458 protocol=https
```

Should it seem strange that the nested "api" key has the same params? I am unclear on which direction to take for debugging these requests. I can't use a service like Charles because they are https right?

Answer (score 0):

Feel like a fool...

the base64EncodedString was an optional.

fix:

```
request.addValue("Basic \(base64EncodedString!)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
```

I was able to get more details about the request with this URLRequest method:

```
print("request header:\(request.allHTTPHeaderFields)")
```